# Import excel sheet in testlink tool

Tags: excel, testing, testcase, testlink

How to import Excel sheet in testLink tool?
I have prepared excel sheet as per,

1. Step actions
2. Expected Results
3. Execution

Still, testlink not allow me to add.
Thanks a lot.